# Two .css files in the same folder, but only one can be found by Django, Windows10

Tags: html, django

As the title described. Please refer to image below:

[image: 1 css file and 1 image file missing]

The two css files is under the same folder and in the template file I copy the link line just changed the file name. Why the abc.css file can't be found as shown in the command line screen? I just can't understand.

Also anther image file is also not found either, also a mystery to me.

[image: image file]

As another try, I moved the png to static root and changed the template code  to

```
src="{% static 'folder.png' %}
```

[image: I moved the png to static root]

Comment: `CTRL + F5` or `CTRL + SHIFT + I` > Network > Disable cache checkbox.

Comment: I add a new picture. It seems to behave as the same.

Comment: First of all, the result you get is because the Django design. we can't add two CSS files directly. StackOverflow has similiar questions, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873194/django-use-multiple-css-file-in-one-html and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386868/django-templates-use-different-css-for-pages and this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474041/how-to-add-multiple-css-file-in-django3-in-a-single-html-file

Comment: Before I post this question I do read the first link you provided. But I thought the reply was telling me that I can use as many .css files as I wish. Contrarily maybe. I'm reading those posts again.

Comment: @yueyongdong I read again all these 3 posts. I don't think all are suitable for my case. The 49873194 and 64474041 just show me I can use css link side by side. The same as my first understanding. The 25386868 just saying one child css link replacing its parent.

Answer (score 1):

`STATIC_URL` setting is no related to what folder you're storing the images in, it's related to the URL of the file located at the server. Let's say that we have an image `foo.png` that's shown somewhere on the website. When you right click on the image and open it in a new tab, the image URL will look something like that `http://localhost:8000/static/foo.png`.

What you want is to make Django look for static files directories so that Django will later collect them into another directory. Let's say you're storing the static files for the whole project in a folder called `static` located at the root of the project, then you have to define the following setting in `settings.py`:

```
# Make sure to import os first

import os

# ...

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

This means that Django will also look for static files in a folder called `static` in our root folder, not just in our apps.
Now we want Django to collect all the static files in one place. Let's add this setting in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

The folder `staticfiles` will hold all static files for the project. Finally, make sure to run the command:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

This command will make Django gather all the static files in `staticfiles` folder.

Comment: I tried what you said but not succeed yet. However I believe you may be correct to some extent and I'll check further in this direction.

Comment: The .css file missing resolved. I made a mistake for APP static folder and project static folder. You wrote python manage.py collectstatic remind me of that. I just the .css file to app/static and the collectstatic action will move them to the specific dedicated resource bin. I forgot this step. I'll read again the Django tutorial.